# Batch SetNull in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, batch, nodata, setnull

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have 100s of GeoTIFFs with NoData set to -99999 and I need to set NoData to null. I can’t seem to get batch SetNull to work. The images are 32 bit float.

Comment: Use model builder iterators to work with your GeoTiffs in a combination of GP tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ModelBuilder in ArcGIS to accomplish this. Create a new model then add an 'iterate raster' iterator. Then attach the set null tool to the output of your iterator.

When you run the model, it should iterate/loop through each raster and apply your set Null to each raster.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-rasters.htm